# Imagemagick identify -verbose reporting drastically different file size from ls -l

Tags: bash, pdf, imagemagick, ubuntu-14.04, ls

Trying to made a bunch of tiffs into web ready pdfs using a bash script and tiff2pdf, but my test suite is coming up with a pretty strange problem. When I `ls -l`...

```
wmcduff@wmcduffscomp:~/Desktop/testdir$ ls -l
total 339896
-rw------- 1 joe joe  2165668 Feb 17 11:48 191611032571.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 joe joe 28114948 Feb 17 11:51 1948010211.pdf
-rw------- 1 joe joe 28114113 Feb 17 11:42 1948010211.tif
-rw-rw-r-- 1 joe joe 29499021 Feb 17 11:51 1948010212.pdf
.
.
.
```

However, if I `identify -verbose 1948010211.pdf`...

```
wmcduff@wmcduffscomp:~/Desktop/testdir$ identify -verbose 1948010211.pdf
Image: 1948010211.pdf
  Format: PDF (Portable Document Format)
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 1085x1456+0+0
  Resolution: 72x72
  Print size: 15.0694x20.2222
  Units: Undefined
  Type: PaletteAlpha
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 16/8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
    alpha: 1-bit
.
.
.
  Properties:
    date:create: 2017-02-17T14:30:11-08:00
    date:modify: 2017-02-17T14:30:11-08:00
    pdf:HiResBoundingBox: 1085.04x1455.84+0+0
    pdf:Version: PDF-1.1  
    signature: b3d978e3b2e7784867b27da677b7288e6674dfcaeb92a8c58f9faf19b20f0655
  Profiles:
    Profile-icc: 2576 bytes
      Description: Artifex Software sRGB ICC Profile
      Manufacturer: Artifex Software sRGB ICC Profile
      Model: Artifex Software sRGB ICC Profile
      Copyright: Copyright Artifex Software 2011
  Artifacts:
    filename: 1948010211.pdf
    verbose: true
  Tainted: True
  Filesize: 2.395MB
  Number pixels: 1.58M
  Pixels per second: 39.49MB
  User time: 0.040u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.040
  Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2016-11-29 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Any idea why the filesize would be so drastically different? Is there something wrong with the command in my bash script ( `tiff2pdf -u i -w 15.07 -l 20.22 -x 300 -y 300 -r o -o "${file/%.tif/.pdf}" "$file"` ) that's making such a big file?

Comment: I am not familiar with `tiff2pdf` but suspect that the `-x 300` and `-y 300` are setting the x,y resolution - maybe try setting these down to 144 to get the sizes down by a factor of 4+.

Comment: They are. I've switched to a new command that is getting things down to under a megabyte; I'm just wondering why the identify and ls would be reporting such drastically different sizes for the same image.

Comment: @WilliamMcDuff: Try upgrading. There has been a bug in past: http://www.multipole.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=20491#p81927. Library might have regressed.

Answer (score 2):

you could argue that the `Filesize` observed in the `identify -verbose` output is misleading: it [refers to the size](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/18b2750bbc8a044f6c98a058f4e962b1616c53ca/MagickCore/identify.c#L1472) of the [BLOB](https://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Blob.html) used [in memory](https://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image++.html#BLOBs), which is different from the amount of storage consumed by the file.

unless you require other parts of the information produced by the `identify -verbose` command, just stick with the filesize that the `ls` utility provides. (alternatively, you might use another tool like `pdfinfo` (part of [Xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/home.html)), or even [mdls](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mdls.1.html) if you are on using Mac OS X, both of which will report the filesize of a PDF).